# MySQL - select rows with a minimum difference

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with `GPS` data, from which I want to select rows with a minimum time difference (based on a unix-timestamp stored with each row), for example get trackpoints with a minimum time-difference of 7 days within the whole table.

In other words, how could I realize something like desciped in php below within a MySQL query?

```
$unixtime = 1;
$interval = 60*60*24*7;

while ($unixtime + $interval < date("U")){
    $SQLtrack = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT unixtime,latitude,longitude FROM $findmeWP_table WHERE unixtime >= ".$unixtime." ORDER BY unixtime ASC LIMIT 1", ARRAY_A);
    foreach ($SQLtrack as $trackpoint) {
        // do stuff
    }
    $unixtime_last = $SQLtrack[count($SQLtrack)-1][unixtime];
    if ($unixtime_last){
        $unixtime = $unixtime_last + $interval;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement does the job. However, you will have to group the results somehow. I therefore took the average coordinates within that period.

```
"SELECT 
    CEIL(unixtime / (60*60*24*7)) as weeklyCeiledTime, 
    AVG(latitude), AVG(longitude) 
    FROM " . $findmeWP_table . "
    WHERE unixtime >= " . $unixtime . " 
    GROUP BY weeklyCeiledTime";
```

Using [CEIL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceil), you can split the timestamps into groups of any interval ranges you like.

Comment: I really like that approach, but generating a average of longitude and latitude in those groups would end in wrong results (example: 1 coordinate in the US and one in China within the same group...).

currently i am trying something like this:
SELECT CEIL(unixtime / (60*60*24*7)) as weeklyCeiledTime, AVG(id), latitude, longitude, unixtimeFROM " . $findmeWP_table . " WHERE unixtime >= 0 GROUP BY weeklyCeiledTime
and the results look pretty promising.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should make `SELF JOIN`

```
select * from tracks t1, tracks t2 WHERE t1.unixtime-t2.unixtime < 3600;
```

Another way:

```
select * from tracks t1, tracks t2 ORDER BY ABS(t1.unixtime-t2.unxitime) LIMIT 10;
```

**But it is slow**!